# Is it possible to condense the primary key/serial?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key, auto-increment

I have a database where everything is linked with foreign keys, so the Postgres knows exactly how the database is laid out.

Let's say I have Table1 and Table2.

Table1 has 3 fields: RID, table2_rid, data.

So `table1.table2_rid` references `table2.RID` and this is expressed with a foreign key. In both the `RID` field is the primary key and is a serial type.

What I would like to know is how to "condense" the primary keys? Say you add 5 records and deleted record number 3. Your primary keys would look like

```
1
2
4
5
```

Well, how do I get to update everywhere so that the primary key (and corresponding foreign keys) can be condensed into

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Is it important to keep everything condensed?  If you have 1000 records in your database and you remove record 1 then you have at least 2 extra updates to run.

Comment: I'm talking more about something you do on a table that has a lot of inserts/deletes per day and doing this as like a monthly maintenance task or something.

Comment: Putting words in scare quotes does not clarify the idiosyncratic meaning that you don't make clear by actually saying what you mean. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. [ask] [Help] [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best if a primary key never changes: Renumbering them is a PITA.

If you need an ID for humans, one that has no gaps, A. Elein Mustain shows [how to create a gapless sequence](http://www.varlena.com/GeneralBits/130.php).

Comment: Well I'm thinking ahead cause we have a table or two that very commonly has transactions rolled back(which increment the primary key's value due to how `serial` works) and has lots of inserts and updates and I would just like to know if in a year or two we begin to face a roll-over problem with 32 bit, if there will be a way to combat it.

Comment: 2^31 is one insert per second for *68 years*.  But if 32 bits might not be enough, then use serial8/bigserial instead of plain serial and you'll be able to do 1000 inserts per second for 0.1 terrayears.

Answer (score 1):

Look into `on update cascade` and `on delete cascade`.

```
create table table_1 (
    id integer
        primary key,
    name char(30)
);
create table table_2 (
    id integer
        primary key,
    table_1_id integer
        references table_1
        on update cascade
        on delete cascade,
    detail char(30)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Except for very rare scenarios, gaps in the PK sequence are just right, to intent to get rid of them is a  bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to do this generally, as [gapless sequences are problematic for performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9985219/398670).

If you want to do it as a cleanup step later you can use the `rank()` window function to achieve the desired effect.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (id integer primary key);
INSERT INTO table1 values (1),(2),(4),(5);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  id serial primary key,
  rid integer references table1(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

insert into table2 (rid) values (1),(1),(4),(4),(4),(5);



UPDATE table1 
  SET id = gapless_id
FROM (
  SELECT *, row_number() OVER () FROM table1
) AS x(old_id, gapless_id)
WHERE id = x.old_id;
```

Result:

```
regress=# select * from table1 ;
 id 
----
  1
  2
  3
  4
(4 rows)
```

If your FK's aren't `ON UPDATE CASCADE` you can `ALTER TABLE` to make them so. This will be quite slow though, especially if there are no indexes on the foreign keys. A faster approach is to do the change in two passes:

- Begin a transaction
- `LOCK TABLE table1;`
- Add a new_id column to table1 and populate it with the new IDs using `row_number()` as shown above
- Drop foreign key constraints referring to table1(id)
- Update all foreign keys to refer to the values in `new_id`
- drop `id` in table1
- rename the `new_id` column of table1 to `id`
- re-create foreign key constraints
- commit