# PostgreSQL gapless sequences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sequence

I'm moving from MySql to Postgres, and I noticed that when you delete rows from MySql, the unique ids for those rows are re-used when you make new ones.  With Postgres, if you create rows, and delete them, the unique ids are not used again.

Is there a reason for this behaviour in Postgres?  Can I make it act more like MySql in this case?

Comment: MySQL shouldn't reuse autoincrement IDs, unless you delete the highest IDs.

Comment: Ah! thanks, that's right.  OK - I can live with that :)

Comment: You shouldn't care about the IDs anyway. They are just meaningless numbers.

Comment: Yeah, I know - but I'm admittedly a bit paranoid about the switch!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004453/postgresql-generate-sequence-with-no-gap

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Sequences have gaps to permit concurrent inserts. Attempting to avoid gaps or to re-use deleted IDs creates horrible performance problems. See the [PostgreSQL wiki FAQ](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_are_there_gaps_in_the_numbering_of_my_sequence.2FSERIAL_column.3F_Why_aren.27t_my_sequence_numbers_reused_on_transaction_abort.3F).

PostgreSQL [`SEQUENCE`s](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) are used to allocate IDs. These only ever increase, and they're exempt from the usual transaction rollback rules to permit multiple transactions to grab new IDs at the same time. This means that if a transaction rolls back, those IDs are "thrown away"; there's no list of "free" IDs kept, just the current ID counter. Sequences are also usually incremented if the database shuts down uncleanly.

Synthetic keys (IDs) are *meaningless* anyway. Their order is not significant, their only property of significance is uniqueness. You can't meaningfully measure how "far apart" two IDs are, nor can you meaningfully say if one is greater or less than another. All you can do is say "equal" or "not equal". Anything else is unsafe. You shouldn't care about gaps.

If you need a gapless sequence that re-uses deleted IDs, you can have one, you just have to give up a huge amount of performance for it - in particular, you cannot have any concurrency on `INSERT`s at all, because you have to scan the table for the lowest free ID, locking the table for write so no other transaction can claim the same ID. Try searching for "postgresql gapless sequence".

The simplest approach is to use a counter table and a function that gets the next ID. Here's a generalized version that uses a counter table to generate consecutive gapless IDs; it doesn't re-use IDs, though.

```
CREATE TABLE thetable_id_counter ( last_id integer not null );
INSERT INTO thetable_id_counter VALUES (0);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_next_id(countertable regclass, countercolumn text) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    next_value integer;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('UPDATE %s SET %I = %I + 1 RETURNING %I', countertable, countercolumn, countercolumn, countercolumn) INTO next_value;
    RETURN next_value;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

COMMENT ON get_next_id(countername regclass) IS 'Increment and return value from integer column $2 in table $1';
```

Usage:

```
INSERT INTO dummy(id, blah) 
VALUES ( get_next_id('thetable_id_counter','last_id'), 42 );
```

Note that when one open transaction has obtained an ID, all other transactions that try to call `get_next_id` will block until the 1st transaction commits or rolls back. This is unavoidable and for gapless IDs and is by design.

If you want to store multiple counters for different purposes in a table, just add a parameter to the above function, add a column to the counter table, and add a `WHERE` clause to the `UPDATE` that matches the parameter to the added column. That way you can have multiple independently-locked counter rows. Do *not* just add extra columns for new counters.

This function does not re-use deleted IDs, it just avoids introducing gaps.

To re-use IDs I advise ... not re-using IDs.

If you really must, you can do so by adding an `ON INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE` trigger on the table of interest that adds deleted IDs to a free-list side table, and removes them from the free-list table when they're `INSERT`ed. Treat an `UPDATE` as a `DELETE` followed by an `INSERT`. Now modify the ID generation function above so that it does a `SELECT free_id INTO next_value FROM free_ids FOR UPDATE LIMIT 1` and if found, `DELETE`s that row. `IF NOT FOUND` gets a new ID from the generator table as normal. Here's an untested extension of the prior function to support re-use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_next_id_reuse(countertable regclass, countercolumn text, freelisttable regclass, freelistcolumn text) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    next_value integer;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('SELECT %I FROM %s FOR UPDATE LIMIT 1', freelistcolumn, freelisttable) INTO next_value;
    IF next_value IS NOT NULL THEN
        EXECUTE format('DELETE FROM %s WHERE %I = %L', freelisttable, freelistcolumn, next_value);
    ELSE
        EXECUTE format('UPDATE %s SET %I = %I + 1 RETURNING %I', countertable, countercolumn, countercolumn, countercolumn) INTO next_value;
    END IF;
    RETURN next_value;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: "in particular, you cannot have any concurrency" --- perform insert, check if it's executed successfully. No reason to lock the whole table (omg)

Comment: @zerkms Are you suggesting that you use something like `INSERT INTO some_table (id, ...) VALUES ( (SELECT max(id)+1 FROM some_table), ...)` and re-try on duplicate key errors? If so, sure, you can do that, but it will perform no better then an approach that uses table- or row-level locking for key generation, usually worse because of the duplicated work. Fundamentally it cannot perform better than a locking based approach because it can still only have one transaction successfully writing at any given time.

Comment: no, I meant about filling gaps. That's what you was talking about, right? The id generator function should be non-blocking, as well as insert procedure, but with unique constraint violation handling.

Comment: "Fundamentally it cannot perform better than a locking based approach because it can still only have one transaction successfully writing at any given time." --- ? Locked for writing table means you won't be able to perform even updates. I cannot imagine something even worse than this.

Comment: @zerkms You're quite right that you can re-use deleted IDs without using a gapless sequence generation procedure. However, most people who want this are usually really looking for gapless sequences.

Comment: @zerkms You have misunderstood. If using locking, the lock is taken on a side-table used for ID generation, so it's only contended by inserts.