# PostgreSQL always creates records with an even ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

my PostgreSQL 9.2 database for some reason skips an ID with every record. Example:

User

```
1258930
1258932
1258934
1258936
```

What would cause this? Any pointer in the right direction to resolve this issue is appreciate. Thank you

Comment: My bet is that you are either rolling back an insert somewhere (consistently) or you call `nextval()` twice for each insert.

Comment: Look at the DB table setup, the column may be set up as auto-increment by 2.

Comment: Can you give the `CREATE SEQUENCE ...` for the sequence you are using?

Comment: Do you have any callbacks on your model?

Comment: The other reason - the `CACHE` value for the sequence is set to `2` and the other cached id isnt used.

Comment: Another (remote) possibility - the same sequence is used for two tables that are both subject to inserts at the same time.

Comment: I'm just curious - why is this a problem? You're not likely to run out of even numbers.

Comment: Good call @DavidAldridge. But that means you'd have to alternate inserts with this table and the other one... but definitely a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

The comments have adequately covered possible reasons:

- multiple `nextval` calls, say one by a `default` and one explicit;
- The same sequence used by more than one table
- Transactions being rolled back

> Any pointer in the right direction to resolve this issue is appreciated

Your key mistake is viewing this as an *issue*. It's entirely normal for gaps to appear in generated sequences. If your DB crashes and restarts, a gap will appear in a sequence. If a transaction rolls back after allocating IDs, a gap will appear in the sequence.

*Your application must be able to deal with this*. It shouldn't care what an ID is, only that it's unique.

For details and for hints if you need truly gapless sequences, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9985219/398670).

Answer (score 0):

Add to Craig's points the key culprit I think you will find is a `DO ALSO` `rule` inserting the new.id into another table.  This will cause double incrementing as `RULES` rewrite queries so new.id ends up being "whatever we did to calculate new.id last time" (which means incrementing the sequence again).

if it is consistent, the most likely cause IMO is someone creating DO ALSO rules without fully understanding the gotchas.