# How to UPDATE or INSERT in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I want to `UPDATE or INSERT` a column in `PostgreSQL` **instead of** doing `INSERT or UPDATE` using `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ...` because there will be more updates than more inserts and also I have an auto incrementing id column that's defined using `SERIAL` so it increments the id column everytime it tries to INSERT or UPDATE and that's not what I want, I want the id column to increase only if it's an INSERT so that all ids would be in an order instead

The table is created like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

    user_id varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    item_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    code_uses bigint NOT NULL,

    UNIQUE(user_id, item_name)
)
```

And the query I used was

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (DEFAULT, 'some_random_id', 'some_random_name', 1)
ON CONFLICT (user_id, item_name)
DO UPDATE SET code_uses = table_name.code_uses + 1;
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Auto-generated/Sequenced IDs in a table should not be expected to be sequential w/no gaps in all instances.  But why don't you provide the statements you're already using?  You've given us nothing to really help you other than a generic description. Ultimately you might need to utilize some PL/pgSQL (SQL Procedural Language) to achieve your goal.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly the problem with `insert ... on conflict..` is

Comment: Added the query, you can look into that now and the problem with `insert ... on conflict ...` is that the ids are having a gap here and I thought like trying to insert many times is not a good idea when in the most cases it would just want to be updated

Comment: gaps in sequence generated values are nothing to worry about. The **only** job of a generated primary key value is to be unique. It does not matter if that value is 1,2, -34 or 48756485.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`Upserts`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/) in PostgreSQL do exactly what you described.

Consider this table and records

```
CREATE TABLE t (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, txt TEXT);
INSERT INTO t (txt) VALUES ('foo'),('bar');

SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY id;

 id | txt 
----+-----
  1 | foo
  2 | bar
(2 Zeilen)
```

Using upserts the id will only increment if a new record is inserted

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,'foo updated'),(3,'new record')
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET txt = EXCLUDED.txt;

SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY id;

 id |     txt     
----+-------------
  1 | foo updated
  2 | bar
  3 | new record
(3 Zeilen)
```

**EDIT** (see coments): this is the expected behaviour of a `serial` column, since they're nothing but a fancy way to use [`sequences`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html). Long story short: using upserts [`the gaps will be inevitable`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL). If you're worried the value might become too big, use `bigserial` instead and let PostgreSQL do its job.

Related thread: [serial in postgres is being increased even though I added on conflict do nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37204749/2275388)

Comment: I'm not sure whether it works here because of you inserting the id directly or not but in my case, I use `DEFAULT` to do it, it skipped a lot of ids and btw, I've added the query I used in the question, please look on that and let me know whether I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @AwesomeStickz I just added a comment to your message.

Comment: Alright, thanks for letting me know about it, I just worried that it may end up reaching max of bigserial too but it's just really really hard to do that so it's not a problem anymore