# running insert on conflict when most queries will result in a conflict

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, query-optimization, sql-insert

In my postgres database, I have a table that is used to map two fields together with a serial primary key, but I will rarely get new mappings. I may get data sent to me 60k times per day (or more) and only get new mappings a handful of times every month. I wrote a query with the `on conflict` clause:

```
insert into mapping_table
values
(field1, field2)
on conflict (field1, field2) do nothing
```

This seems to work as expected! But I'm wondering if running the insert query tens of thousands of times per day when a mapping rarely needs to be added is problematic somehow? And if so, is there a better way to do that?

I'm also not sure if there's a problem with the serial primary key. [As expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37204749/serial-in-postgres-is-being-increased-even-though-i-added-on-conflict-do-nothing), the value auto increments even though there is a conflict. I don't have any logic that expects that the primary key won't have gaps, but the numbers will get large very fast, and I'm not sure if that could become a problem in the future.

Comment: "*and I'm not sure if that could become a problem in the future*" - if you burn 10000 values per second, 24/7 without any pause, it will take 9223372036854775807 years until the sequence is exhausted

Comment: Or 98 years, for 60k a day, with a regular (integer) SERIAL.

Answer (score 1):

There are 86,400 seconds in a day.  So, 60k times per day is less than once per second.

Determining the conflict is a lookup in a unique index, and then perhaps some additional checking for locking and so on.  Under most circumstances, this would be an acceptable load on the system.

Answer (score 1):

`on conflict` seems like the right tool for this. It is built-in, probably fairly optimized, and implements the logic you want with a straight-forward syntax.

*If* you want to avoid "burning" sequence numbers though, an alternative is `not exists`, to check if a row exists *before* inserting it:

```
insert into mapping_table (field1, field2)
select *
from (values (field1, field2)) v
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from mapping_table mp 
    where mp.field1 = v.field1 and mp.field2 = v.field2
)
```

This query would take advantage of the already existing index on `(field1, field2)`. It will most likely not be faster than `on conflict` though, and probably slower.