# Moving "Craig's" gapless sequence to other schema fails?

Tags: postgresql

While trying to move Craig Ringer's [PostgreSQL gapless sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984196/postgresql-gapless-sequences/9985219#9985219) example in to another schema `'test'` I get an error. The query

```
INSERT INTO test.dummy(id, blah)
VALUES ( test.get_next_id('test.thetable_id_counter','last_id'), 42 );
```

errors with

```
relation "test.thetable_id_counter" does not exist
UPDATE "test.thetable_id_counter" SET "test.last_id" = "test...
       ^
```

yet the query:

```
SELECT to_regclass('test.thetable_id_counter');
```

does not result in NULL.

Comment: In a `format()` call with a `regclass` argument, you should use `%s` instead of `%I`. I've amended Craig's answer.

Comment: Thanks @NickBarnes